# Inverse trigonometric functions in Calculator

Tags: macos, applications

Is there a way to calculate inverse trigonometric functions in El Capitan's Calculator (ie. arcsine, arccosine, arctangent, etc.)? I've tried the usual alt, cmd, ctrl modifiers with the sin/cos/tan buttons to no avail. I'm especially annoyed because Spotlight does calculate arctangents and the result is claimed to come from Calculator itself, so I don't know if they dumbed the interface down or what.

Examples of operations that work from Spotlight but I have no clue how to do from Calculator:

```
atan(1)  # arctangent of 1 in radians
atand(1) # arctangent of 1 in degrees
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hit the shift key **in** Calculator in older versions of OS X to get all inverse trigonometric but also some other functions:

[image]

[image]

In El Capitan it works with the "2nd" button (the real keyboard's shift key should work as well):

[image]

[image]

Comment: D'oh, the `2nd` button did it. But `shift` did not. Any idea why? I'm expecting the buttons to switch to their alternate functions while I keep it pressed, but nothing happens.

Comment: I can't get calculator to show the inverse functions. MacOS 10.13.5 (High Sierra). Are these still valid? I tried pressing or keeping pressed SHIFT but nothing. As for the "2nd button" I can't understand which exactly is this on the keyboard. Is it a key or a combination?

Comment: @AndreiRinea its 2nd button in the calculator interface, not a key from the keyboard, hope you solve it

Comment: @AndreiRînea is right, Shift does not work anymore. But the "2nd" button (literally how it is called in the UI) worked.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate **atan()** and **atand()** in **Calculator** under OS X El Capitan, do the following…

1. Open **Calculator**.
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> on the  Mac’s keyboard, to show the **Scientific Calculator**.
3. To calculate *inverse trigonometric functions*, click the **2<sup>nd</sup>** button *(left side, second row, first button)* on the calculator (or you can press and hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key on the Mac’s keyboard during a given operation) in order to change the **tan** button to display as: **tan <sup>-1</sup>**
4. To change between calculating *degrees* and *radians*, toggle the button in the lower left corner of the **Scientific Calculator** between **Deg** and **Rad**.

   - The default is to calculate *degrees* and the **Rad** button is shown.
   - To  calculate *radians*, click the **Rad** button so it shows **Deg**. Note that **Rad** also appears in the left side of the *main display*.

---

Result for **atand(1)**:

[image: atand(1)]

Result for **atan(1)**:

[image: atan(1)]

Comment: It was somewhat strange to get such big radians, haha. Thanks for pointing out that degrees are the default

Comment: I can't get calculator to show the inverse functions. MacOS 10.13.5 (High Sierra). Are these still valid? I tried pressing or keeping pressed SHIFT but nothing. As for the "2nd button" I can't understand which exactly is this on the keyboard. Is it a key or a combination?

Comment: @Andrei Rinea Yes, what I've stated in my answer is still valid for macOS 10.13.5 As to which is the **2nd** button, well I've plainly and clearly described which button it is and as shown in the images it's clearly visible. I'd suggest you reread the answer and pay particular attention to #3.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks! I was looking for the 2<sup>nd</sup> button on the physical keyboard (duh!!!)